# Why does $\dim W = \dim V$ only if $W = V$ for a vector space $V$ and its subspace $W$? Removing one element from W renders this false

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W$ be a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. Then $\dim W = \dim V$ if and only if $W = V$.

Why is this? I understand the proof I was given (which uses the fact that any set of exactly $n$ linearly independent vectors, where $n = \dim V$, in $V$ must be a basis of $V$).

But what about this reasoning: remove one element from $W$, so long as that element doesn't make up a basis of $W$ (though if there is more than one basis then even this condition isn't necessary). Now $W \neq V$, but $\dim W = \dim V$, no?

I am guessing that the reasoning is in some way flawed. But why is it flawed/in what way?

Comment: Your reasoning is not clear. Can you spell it out?

Comment: Removing one element from $W$ will (in general) not result in a vector space.

Comment: @user1892304 Ohhh I see, that makes sense thank you! And that would be because it would result in a linear sum or scalar multiple of one of the other items in the space to no longer be in it?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument fails because after removing one element from $W$, what you get is not a vector space anymore (unless you are working over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $\dim W=1$).

Comment: Or if the underlying field is $\Bbb Z_2$ and $\dim(W) = 1$

Comment: That makes sense, don't know how I didn't realize that. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Removing an element from $W=\{0\}$ will not give you a vector space. The onyl working case is indeed a one-dimensional over $\Bbb F_2$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I've edited my answer. Thank you.